# Is "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" obsolete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ancient **MVC2** solution that I migrated to **MVC5** (Visual Studio 2013).

I'd like to update the old libraries used in the project with the new ones.

I have by eg. the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` library. 
Is it obsolete as by now?

I ask because that library references

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.4.js" />
```

but I upgraded the jQuery (I use the jQuery v1.8.3 by now).

If it with what to replace (like `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`(?))

**PS.**
In a default MVC project Visual Studio 2013 proposes the folowing "validation" scripts:

```
jquery.validate-vsdoc.js
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
```

Comment: I set up a new site and it uses the following three validation scripts: jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js, jquery.validate.js, jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Comment: From what I can remember `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not for validation, but for some ajax helpers like `@Ajax.BeginForm`, `@Ajax.ActionLink` to function ajax activities. So if you don't use them in your page, it is not needed.

Comment: How can I know if I still use them? Perhaps I upgraded some libraries that replace it functionality...But is there a way to see the "references" to that "ajax" library? I don't have any `@Ajax.BeginForm `or `@Ajax.ActionLink` in the solution's code...

Comment: I have `@Ajax.GlobalizationScript`, but this is defined in the System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions... library

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is a Microsoft library for supporting `@Ajax.*` helpers, this is a plugin that unobtrusively sets up `jQuery Ajax`.

If you use `@Ajax` helpers in your code, like [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or [BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), along with updating `jQuery` you have to update the Microsoft [jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/3.2.3), otherwise you can remove it.

If you remove reference to the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`, `@Ajax` helpers will be working as regular `@Html` helpers.

> How can I know if I still use them?

Try to look for the usages of these methods.

Comment: What is this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/ then?

Comment: it this still valid? since it is not listed under the newer mvc5.x http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn#ASPNET_Web_Forms_and_Ajax_Releases_on_the_CDN_15

Comment: MS Ajax is a webforms thing with `UpdatePanel` etc... It has nothing to do with this plugin. "Jquery unobtrusive-ajax" is NOT obsolete. Latest version has been released 2 months ago (I'm witing this in 2018)

Answer (score -5):

You were asking how you can make sure whether you have the latest jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js installed (or how to check whether it may be obsolete).

Visual Studio 2010+ comes with the NuGet package manager console (PMC). To see if your project's external references (like, e.g., unobtrusive AJAX) are still up to date:

1. Open your project in Visual Studio
2. Right-click your project in Solution Explorer
3. Select "Manage NuGet packages"
4. Select the package you want to update (unobtrusive AJAX a/o unobtrusive validation)
5. Here you can see whether you're using the latest version of the external reference or if an update is available.
6. Press the [Update] button.