# What is the difference between Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive and Microsoft Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-ajax

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC Application (C# and razor).
I am wondering what is the difference between those 2 nuget packages:

- Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive
- Microsoft Ajax

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Microsft jQuery Unobtrusive** replaces the [obsolete **Microsoft Ajax**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782697/are-microsoftajax-js-microsoftmvcajax-js-and-microsoftmvcvalidation-js-obsolete).

After importing the package to your project, **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js** allows you to use the `Ajax*` AjaxHelpers in the Razor views.

However, many recommend against using the AjaxHelpers in favor coding these yourself with plain jQuery.

It seems in [MVC6 they have removed the AjaxHelpers](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2015).

Which updates the question [Is "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388813/is-jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-js-obsolete)